# Can `git log` "fold" changes merged from master into fewer lines?

Tags: git, github, merge

I work on a project with hundreds of contributors pushing daily. As I work on a feature branch, I like to merge master in frequently, but when I do, my graph log (`git log --graph` or `git log --graph --oneline`) shows hundreds of commits from master before showing the changes from my branch, e.g.:

```
*   f93e1e0f107 (HEAD -> cshroba/my-feature-branch, origin/cshroba/my-feature-branch) Merge branch 'master' into cshroba/my-feature-branch
|\
| * 3029c915d02 (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) someone else's commit
| * 9f08e615205 someone else's commit
| * 7722734920e someone else's commit
| * 4eb08b2342d someone else's commit
| * 15f5521b2c8 someone else's commit
| * e4386c33ffd someone else's commit
| * b03a944e2e8 someone else's commit
| * 2a84cd2a005 someone else's commit
| * 68a1f6eedd1 someone else's commit
| * 3eb35aa1ae1 someone else's commit
| * 1b01a894ee6 someone else's commit
| * 146c3f63eaf someone else's commit
| * e47660b4b21 someone else's commit
| * 834f628c723 someone else's commit
| * 3e6cff1c109 someone else's commit
| * 67468c547cf someone else's commit
| * dcb38ce901b someone else's commit (assume there are hundreds more that I'm omitting here)
| * 7722734920e someone else's commit
* | 61cf1c2c5a1 My change from my branch
* | 8e052ed090e My change from my branch
* | 94159085e8f My change from my branch
* | 25935b173ad My change from my branch
* | fdfb73c2877 My change from my branch
* | 90294f975eb My change from my branch
* | b69ed8b8ba2 My change from my branch
* | 1fd4f2dc1e6 My change from my branch
* | c048b4a6b93 My change from my branch
* | 4567a677d9e My change from my branch
|/  
* c8301756fd2 The change from master that I initially branched off
```

I don't care what specific changes happened in master, so is there a way for me to fold them into just one or a few lines, such as:

```
*   f93e1e0f107 (HEAD -> cshroba/my-feature-branch, origin/cshroba/my-feature-branch) Merge branch 'master' into cshroba/my-feature-branch
|\
| * 3029c915d02 (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) someone else's commit
| *             < 812 commits (hidden) >
| * 7722734920e someone else's commit
* | 61cf1c2c5a1 My change from my branch
* | 8e052ed090e My change from my branch
* | 94159085e8f My change from my branch
* | 25935b173ad My change from my branch
* | fdfb73c2877 My change from my branch
* | 90294f975eb My change from my branch
* | b69ed8b8ba2 My change from my branch
* | 1fd4f2dc1e6 My change from my branch
* | c048b4a6b93 My change from my branch
* | 4567a677d9e My change from my branch
|/  
* c8301756fd2 The change from master that I initially branched off
```

Comment: Besides `--first-parent`, consider also `--simplify-by-decoration` and many of the other simplifiers listed in [the `git log` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use [`--first-parent`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---first-parent) to only follow the first parent of a merge commit, same as HEAD~. The first parent is what a branch was merged into, in this case `master`. For example, the first parent of `f93e1e0f107` is `61cf1c2c5a1`.

```
* f93e1e0f107 (HEAD -> cshroba/my-feature-branch, origin/cshroba/my-feature-branch) Merge branch 'master' into cshroba/my-feature-branch
* 61cf1c2c5a1 My change from my branch
* 8e052ed090e My change from my branch
* 94159085e8f My change from my branch
* 25935b173ad My change from my branch
* fdfb73c2877 My change from my branch
* 90294f975eb My change from my branch
* b69ed8b8ba2 My change from my branch
* 1fd4f2dc1e6 My change from my branch
* c048b4a6b93 My change from my branch
* 4567a677d9e My change from my branch  
* c8301756fd2 The change from master that I initially branched off
```

A similar option is [`--merges`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---merges) which will only show merge commits. However, since you're committing directly to master, this does not apply; it would only show `f93e1e0f107`. It is useful if you're following a strict [feature branch workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow).

I don't know if there's a way to show just a few commits in each merged branch.